# What do I call a shape with constant Minkowski distance from its center?

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

When *p* is 1 (= using Manhattan distance), it's a square.

When *p* is 2 (= using Euclidean distance), it's a circle.

Is there a term for a set of points with constant Minkowski distance from its center, either for all such shapes, or only for one of p < 1, 1 < p < 2, or 2 < p?

Comment: You can call it a “Minkowski circle”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the term "[superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse)", and in the special case of the "supercircle", the formula seems to be equivalent to having a constant Minkowski distance.

Comment: "astroid" is a special case, where p=2/3: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Astroid.html